# Appending arrays custom function not working

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, append

I have the following arrays in my project:

```
var bottom = [[CGPoint]]() // bottom = [bottom1,...,bottom5]
var left = [[CGPoint]]() // left = [left1,...,left5]
var top = [[CGPoint]]() // top = [top1,..., top5]
var right = [[CGPoint]]() // right = [right1,...,right5]
var bottomExtended = [[CGPoint]]()

directionArray = [right, bottom, left, top]
enum Direction: Int  {

case right = 0, bottom, left, top

}
```

`bottom` and `bottomExtended` are of the same length. I have merged them successful using the following code:

```
for i in 0..<bottom.count {
        bottom[i].appendContentsOf(bottomExtended[i])
    }
```

I wrote a general function for merging the arrays:

```
func addToDirectionArray    (direction:Direction, addArray:[[CGPoint]])  {
    let enumRawValue = direction.rawValue

    for i in 0..<directionArray[enumRawValue].count {
        directionArray[enumRawValue][i].appendContentsOf(addArray[i])
    }
}
```

I tested it with the following:

```
addToDirectionArray(.bottom, addArray: bottomExtended)
```

but it's not merging the arrays. I've checked the array count. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Arrays are value types. You appended not to reference to bottom array, but to it copy inside directionArray

Comment: Does your code compile? This `directionArray[enumRawValue].count` is a compilation error, since `Int` has no `count`.

Comment: @MaxPevsner directionArray have type [[[CGPoint]]]. Hilarious404, rewrite your code with NSArray (reference type) if you wish, but I believe that better rethink task and write custom class or structure, depends on expected behavior.

Comment: @ShadowOf I foresee issues with manipulating the array if I change it to an NSArray. I would be grateful if you could show me an example of how a custom class or structure could solve my issue.

Answer (score -1):

I think the cause of your problems is that you are declaring arrays of arrays of CGPoint instead of arrays of CGPoints.

Try with:

```
var bottom = [CGPoint]()
```

and also with the other arrays do the same obviously

EDIT: I don't know why this has been downvoted. If arrays of arrays is intended behaviour, then it works fine. Just made a playground to prove it.

[image]
Obviously, the array which you are appending elements to is the one inside directionArray (Last line of code). The original bottom array is not modified because directionArray contains a COPY of bottom array, not the original bottom array, because of this line

```
directionArray = [right, bottom, left, top]
```